# How to create datatable in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I tried create and fill  a simple DataTable

Result of this code :

```
   Order     Driver
    1
               1
```

But I want to show on same row like this   :

```
  Order     Driver
    1         1
```

Where is my wrong in this code ?

```
   public DataTable MethodName(string Param)
    {
        DataRow dr;
        DataTable dt= new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Order", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Driver", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

      if(AnotherMethod1(Param))
       {    dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Order"] = 1;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
       }
      else 
      {     dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Order"] = 0;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
      }
      if(AnotherMethod2(Param))
      {     dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Driver"] = 1;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
      }
      else
      {     dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Driver"] = 0;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
       }
      return dt;
   }
```

Comment: Because you are adding a new row containing one field. Add both columns to the same row.

Comment: Your wrong is that you're creating a new row for each value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding a row every time you set value to a different column.

Try this:

```
public DataTable MethodName(string Param)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Order", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("Driver", typeof(Int32));

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Order"] = AnotherMethod1(Param) ? 1 : 0;
    dr["Driver"] = AnotherMethod2(Param) ? 1 : 0;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);           
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public DataTable MethodName(string Param)
{
    DataRow dr;
    DataTable dt= new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Order", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Driver", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    if(AnotherMethod1(Param))
    {    
        dr["Order"] = 1;
    }
    else 
    {     
        dr["Order"] = 0;            
    }
    if(AnotherMethod2(Param))
    {     
        dr["Driver"] = 1;
    }
    else
    {     
        dr["Driver"] = 0;            
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    return dt;
}
```